# Browserify run a single file

Tags: browserify

I'm trying to build up an embeddable script that runs onload with browserify.

So it compiles all the modules together, wraps them in a closure as expected, but what then? I can't figure out how to tell browserify to actually run one file. ie that 1 particular file is the entry point. For instance, if I had a file like so:

```
// runner.js
var app = require('./app'),
    $   = require('jquery');

$(function(){
  app.run();
});
```

How do I tell browserify during build step that I want this file to actually run. For instance can I wrap it in a self invoking function?

I've read that you can expose globals with browserify, but I don't want to expose every file in my app as a global that the app can see. Ideally I don't want to expose anything, I just want the script to run.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that, looks like browserify does indeed run the files.

I forgot I was playing with the `--standalone` option and that doesn't actually seem to run anything, but *I think* let's you just build a module that someone else can call.